# How to stay logged in flutter application?

Tags: flutter, symfony

In my application flutter after a user logs in, I would like the session to remain open. That is, if a user opens the app, he logs in, if he were to close the application and open it later I would like him to be still logged in and not have to re-enter his credentials. Backend I use symfony 2

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to have more information about your technological approach. Just so I can provide a better answer.

With the information you provided:

I really like to use the **[FlutterSecureStorage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage)**. Here you can read and write encrypted information. You can use it this way:

```
await storage.write(key: 'sessionToken', value: accessToken);
await storage.read(key:'sessionToken');
```

So you can use those methods in your main file or in the case you have an state based approach, with [Riverpod](https://riverpod.dev/) or a similar one, I suggest to create an StateProvider for session management.

A possible and fast solution for your answer:

main.dart

```
String? sessionToken = await storage.read(key:'sessionToken');
if (sessionToken.isNotEmpty) {
   // your user is logged in
} else {
   // you must redirect to login
}
```

This has been a basic approach, note that you also have to check if the token has expired and the flow related to this.
Also, after the user logs in, remember to write the sessionToken in the SecureStorage.